# Splitting value to two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that stores the VIN numbers and delivery dates of vehicles based on a code. I want to be able to get one row with three columns of data.

I have tried the following

```
SELECT DISTINCT VIN, MAX(TRANSACTION_DATE) AS DELIVERY_DATE
  FROM "TABLE"
 WHERE DELIVERY_TYPE ='025'
   AND VIN IN ('XYZ')
 GROUP BY VIN
UNION ALL
SELECT VIN, MAX(TRANSACTION_DATE) AS OTHER_DELIVERY_DATE
  FROM "TABLE"
 WHERE DELIVERY_TYPE !='025'
   AND VIN IN ('XYZ')
 GROUP BY VIN;

When I run this I get

 VIN  DELIVERY_DATE
 XYZ    26-dec-18
 XYZ    01-MAY-19

current data format in table:

 VIN  TRANSACTION_DATE
 XYZ      26-DEC-18
 XYZ      01-MAY-19

Required format:

 VIN   DELIVERY_DATE   OTHER_DELIVERY DATE
 XYZ      26-DEC-18           01-MAY-19
```

Answer (score 1):

use `conditional aggregation`

```
SELECT  VIN,
        MAX (CASE WHEN DELIVERY_TYPE ='025' AND
                       VIN IN ('XYZ') then TRANSACTION_DATE end) AS DELIVERY_DATE
        MAX(CASE WHEN DELIVERY_TYPE !='025' AND
                       VIN IN ('XYZ') then TRANSACTION_DATE end) AS OTHER_DELIVERY
  FROM "TABLE"     
 GROUP BY VIN
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT VIN,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DELIVERY_TYPE = 25 THEN TRANSACTION_DATE END) AS DELIVERY_DATE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DELIVERY_TYPE <> 25 THEN TRANSACTION_DATE END) AS TRANSACTION_DATE
FROM TABLE
WHERE VIN IN ('XYZ')
GROUP BY VIN;
```

Note that `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never used with `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CROSS APPLY

```
DECLARE @Cars TABLE (VIN VARCHAR(100), DELIVERY_TYPE VARCHAR(3), TRANSACTION_DATE DATE)
INSERT INTO @Cars
(VIN, DELIVERY_TYPE , TRANSACTION_DATE)
VALUES
('XYZ', '025', '20181226'), ('XYZ', '030', '20190319')
```

I needed above code to be able to run without a table and data, all you need is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.VIN, DD.DELIVERY_DATE, TD.TRANSACTION_DATE
    FROM @Cars C
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(TRANSACTION_DATE) DELIVERY_DATE FROM @Cars D WHERE D.DELIVERY_TYPE = '025' AND D.VIN = C.VIN) DD
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(TRANSACTION_DATE) TRANSACTION_DATE FROM @Cars D WHERE D.DELIVERY_TYPE = '025' AND D.VIN = C.VIN) TD
```

If you need to transpond not two but a lot more columns, I'd suggest using PIVOT TABLE as more appropriate, but for two columns either CROSS APPLY or conditional aggregation will do the trick.